# How to track animation in iOS UIView animations

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; // animate the following:
gearKnob.center = startedAtPoint;
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This is animation, which moves UIImageView (gearKnob) from point to point. The problem is that when object is moving, I need to change background accordingly, so I need to track every UIImageView position when it is moving. How can I track its position? Is there any method or delegate to do that?

Comment: You are not supposed to. Add a similar animation for the background with the same duration and the same timing function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you *really* have to, here is an efficient way to do it.
The trick is to use a CADisplayLink timer and read the animated property from layer.presentationLayer.

```
@interface MyViewController ()
...
@property(nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
...
@end

@implementation MyViewController {

- (void)animateGearKnob {

   // invalidate any pending timer
   [self.displayLink invalidate];

   // create a timer that's synchronized with the refresh rate of the display
   self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateDuringAnimation)];
   [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

   // launch the animation
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{

       gearKnob.center = startedAtPoint;

   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

       // terminate the timer when the animation is complete
       [self.displayLink invalidate];
       self.displayLink = nil;
   }];
}

- (void)updateDuringAnimation {

    // Do something with gearKnob.layer.presentationLayer.center

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As David wrote, you are probably better off running a second animation in parallel.

If you need to pseudo-animate something using a timer, you may want to try out [CPAccelerationTimer](https://github.com/yangmeyer/CPAccelerationTimer), which allows you to set a Bézier timing curve for the callbacks.

If you really must, you should be able to do key-value observing on `gearKnob.layer.presentationLayer.center`. The layer returned by [-[CALayer presentationLayer]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/presentationLayer) is “a close approximation of the layer that is currently being displayed onscreen. While an animation is in progress, you can retrieve this object and use it to get the current values for those animations.”

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use direct animation in that case
You have to use your own timer and move the knob
use :  NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:
and in the selector move the knob and get the position